# Neo4j Update node with aggregated count

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to take a count and set a property of a node with the value. e.g the following query:

```
MATCH (n:node)-[]->() return n, count(*)
```

returns the node alongside each of the counts. I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
MATCH (n:node)-[]->() set n.relationCount = count(*)
```

However executing the above returns an error:

```
Aggregations should not be used like this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking through similar questions and although i didn't find the precise use of aggregates in setting data I did manage to reverse engineer an example into this:

```
MATCH (n:node)-[]->()
WITH n, count(*) as c
SET n.data = c
```

Which appears to work!

Comment: The reason for the restricted usage is that aggregations require a grouping key which provides the context for the aggregation (otherwise it's across all rows). That can be expressed clearly in a WITH clause (which is where we allow them), but if used in a SET (especially after a more complex pattern), it can become ambiguous, which we want to avoid.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I also found that when I was analysing the results this version of count behaved oddly when it came to loops of nodes. `count(distinct *)` however worked how I initially expected it to work. Can understand why odd behaviour occurred and i guess it's more performant than counting distinct nodes? But definitely something to watch out for :)

Comment: Yes, it's important to understand that when you want to count distinct nodes, you need `count(distinct ...)`. Otherwise the same entities will be counted based on their occurrences, rather than once per distinct entity. There are use cases that require both behaviors, so the DISTINCT keyword allows you to choose which you need.